# How correct that Access Violation error in c?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, fgets

I´m getting a "Access violation writing location" error when I run that code. I know that probably is because I´m trying change a const value, but I dont know how correct the code.

OBS: I want create ***n*** arrays to storage strings with 25 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    //variables
    int i = 0, n = 0;

    //code
    scanf("%d\n", &n); //define the number of arrays
    char* exp;
    exp = (char*)malloc(n * 25); //allocate memory for the string size
    

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
 
        //takes strings from keyboard
        fgets(exp[i], n*25, stdin); //the below error takes place here.
        
    }
    
    //prints the first string taked from stdin
    printf("%s", exp[0]);

}
```

ERROR:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBC6EC916F (ucrtbased.dll) in BEE-URI 1022.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCD.

Comment: Turn on warnings in your compiler and the error will become crystal clear very fast. You should never suppress warnings unless you know what you're doing, and even if you do you should leave a note saying why.

Comment: You call `fgets` with the value stored in `exp[i]` (which is uninitialized) and `fgets` assumes that random value is a valid pointer and writes some stuff there - writing into a random place in memory will make it explode.

Comment: If `n = 0` and `malloc` is called with `n * 25`... what do you expect it to return?

Comment: Also `printf("%s", exp[0]);` is trying to print a single character as if it were a string.  Which will also explode.  IF you turn on extra warnings it will tell you about that too: https://godbolt.org/z/z9eW384vs

Comment: Take out `\n` from scanf format string

Comment: If you don't see error messages for this code then change your compiler settings, it's a complete waste of time to try running erroneous code

Comment: You say you want `n` arrays of 25 characters, but what you malloc is one array of `n * 25` characters. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument expression of this call shall have the type `char *`, So instead of

```
fgets(exp[i], n*25, stdin);
```

you need at least to write

```
fgets(exp, n*25, stdin);
```

And the used conversion specifier

```
printf("%s", exp[0]);
```

is also incorrect. Either use

```
printf("%c", exp[0]);
```

or

```
printf("%s", exp);
```

Pay attention to that it is unclear what you are trying to achieve using this for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    fgets(exp, n*25, stdin); //the below error takes place here.
    
}
```

Maybe you mean something like the following

```
char ( *exp )[25];
exp = malloc( n * sizeof( char[25] ) );

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    fgets(exp[i], sizeof( exp[i] ), stdin);
}

// either
// printf( "%s", exp[0] );
// or the loop below
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf( "%s", exp[i] );
}

free( exp );
```

Comment: @Passerby Thanks. I have updated the code.

Comment: Really thanks for you answer. I wrote some commenters. Please, see if my goals are more clear.

Comment: @RodrigoDias I have already written about the possible task you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want `n` arrays of 25 characters each, but what you `malloc` is one array of `n * 25` characters. I think you want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    char **exp;

    scanf("%d", &n);                // get the number of arrays
    exp = malloc(n * sizeof *exp);  // allocate memory for n string pointers
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        exp[i] = malloc(25 * sizeof **exp);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fgets(exp[i], 25, stdin);   // takes strings from keyboard
    printf("%s", exp[0]);           // print 1st string taken from stdin
}
```

Note that you should also check the return values from your `malloc` calls so you know if they succeeded or failed. Same with `fgets` and `scanf`.

BTW, remember that a string of 25 characters can only hold 24 characters because you must have room for the terminating null character.